# Solving a matrix equation $AB=CD$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Suppose that $A_{2n\times 2k},B_{2k\times 2k},C_{2n\times 2n},D_{2n\times 2k}$ are matrices with $k\geq n$. Both $A,C$ are known and $C$ is upper triangular.

I'm trying to find $B,D$ such that $AB=CD$, $B$ is upper triangular and $D$ is a block matrix which looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D'_{n\times k} & 0\\
0 & D''_{n\times k}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

My feeling is that $B,C$ are transformations that convert $A$ to $D$, with $C$ known. I checked some particular cases but I don't know whether there exists a solution (or solutions) in general.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm or just a proof that $B,D$ exist?

Comment: When $C$ is invertible, this is equivalent to solving the case when $C=I.$

Comment: Hi abiessu, I am looking for a proof of the existence of B, D.